# Import data from a spreadsheet into latex and create multiple pdf files for each row in LaTeX

Tags: database

I have a form which I assign to people to fill them out as a google form, and get the responses in a spreadsheet (xlsx or ods file formats). I need to file a report based on their answers, which means I have to generate a pdf file for each row of the spreadsheet. Here is an example. Imagine this is the first three rows of the soreadsheet:

```
Name Question1 Question2 Question3
Name1 Answer1.1 Answer2.1 Answer 3.1
Name2 Answer1.2 Answer2.2 Answer 3.2
```

What I need to get is two pdf files named `Name1.pdf` and `Name2.pdf` which first one contains something like this:

```
Name: Name1
Question1: Answer1.1
Question2: Answer2.1
Question3: Answer3.1
```

And so on. I was thinking that one might write a script in python and read each row of the file and give it as an input to `pdflatex` command on a template file, but I don't have much ideas on how to really start on this.

Comment: What I would do is export the files to .csv format, transform them with a script to replace field separators with newlines, and use `textmerg` to process the data file. For example, I export with ; as field separator and nothing around text to .csv. Then `gawk 'BEGIN { RS=";"; ORS="\n" } { print }' input.csv > output.dat` prepares the file for merge. This will standardly give you a single pdf but either you could adjust this (I think) or you can 'burst' the pdf using something like `pdftk`. I don't know this is the best way, though. It is probably a function of what I already know how to do!

Comment: Something like (in `bash`) `split -l 1 myfile.csv name && sed -i 's/;/\n/g' name*` will do: (1) split each line of your `.csv` file into a new file with the prefix `namea` (thus, your three lines would become: `nameaa` `nameab` and `nameac`); (2) sed takes each instance of `;` and replaces it with a newline (the `\n`).  This gives you the files broken down into discrete pieces which you can `latex` in which ever way you choose.  Note that the `;` delimiter needs to be chosen in your export to `.csv`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little more detail...

If I start with a spreadsheet which looks like yours, I then `save as`, pick `.csv` and choose `;` as field separator and nothing to surround text. (This is in `calc` but I assume other software offers similar functionality.)

This produces the following `.csv` file which I saved as `question.csv`:

```
Name;Question1; Question2; Question3
Name1;Answer1.1;Answer2.1;Answer 3.1
Name2;Answer1.2;Answer2.2;Answer 3.2
```

I then run

```
gawk 'BEGIN { RS=";"; ORS="\n" } { print }' question.csv > question.dat
```

which produces `question.dat`:

```
Name
Question1
 Question2
 Question3
Name1
Answer1.1
Answer2.1
Answer 3.1
Name2
Answer1.2
Answer2.2
Answer 3.2
```

We don't especially want a pdf with the headers in it but I think it can be useful to have a 'dummy' page just to make sure everything ends up in the right places. However, you can easily exclude this if you prefer. It would be good to tidy up the stray spaces at the start of some lines, though:

```
sed -i 's/^  *//' question.dat
```

gets me `question.dat`:

```
Name
Question1
Question2
Question3
Name1
Answer1.1
Answer2.1
Answer 3.1
Name2
Answer1.2
Answer2.2
Answer 3.2
```

You can now use the data in a template `.tex` file, formatting it as you wish. Just for example, I've used the `description` environment as I don't know how long the answers might be so `tabular` seemed potentially problematic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textmerg}

\begin{document}

\Fields{\subjectname\questionone\questiontwo\questionthree}

\Merge{question.dat}{%

\begin{description}
    \item[Name:] \subjectname
    \item[Question1:] \questionone
    \item[Question2:] \questiontwo
    \item[Question3:] \questionthree
\end{description}

\cleardoublepage
}

\end{document}
```

This produces a 3 page pdf file. To separate the pages into separate pdfs, I used `pdftk` as follows:

```
pdftk question.pdf burst
```

This gives me `pg_0001.pdf`, `pg_0002.pdf` and `pg_0003.pdf`. The remaining problem is therefore to rename them using the names from the original file. This might be problematic if you have names with accented characters etc. Assuming nothing deviates too far from what your system will accept:

```
ls pg_000* > pdf.list
sed 's/\;.*$//' question.csv > name.list
```

If you need to clean up the name list, do it now. For example, you might need to remove spaces:

```
sed -i 's/ //g' name.list
```

Then create a file of `mv` commands. I'm doing it this way because if you have a lot of data, storing all the names as arguments is likely to exceed the capacity of your shell. This way, each data entry gets its own command.

```
paste -d ' ' pdf.list name.list | sed -e 's/^/mv /' -e 's/$/.pdf/' > cmds.list
```

Now you can run the commands with e.g. `sh cmds.list`.

This gives me three pdfs named `Name.pdf`, `Name1.pdf` and `Name2.pdf`.

`Name.pdf` is the dummy run:

[image: dummy run]

`Name1.pdf` corresponds to the first data row:

[image: first data row]

and `Name2.pdf` to the second:

[image: second data row]

Obviously, this process can be tweaked in various ways and you can combine things in scripts etc. It can also be made more efficient, especially, I think, for the renaming. But the best way to do that probably depends on the details and hopefully this would give you a starting point if you end up using something like this workflow.

Comment: Interesting.  I think I'd `split` the `.csv` first: it should simplify the process.  (No need to use `pdftk`, e.g.)

Comment: @jon True. The merging stage is more complex in that case, though, but it would definitely simplify things later. This is actually something I use when I *don't* want separate pdfs so, as I said above, it isn't necessarily the best solution here. More a function of what I already know how to do!

Comment: Hmm, true.  I've never used `textmerg` so I didn't think about that. I suppose there must be a way to `\input` a file as a variable...

Comment: @jon Probably. I'm just not sure how to do that. At least, I am not sure how to do it at all tidily. (I can think of ways to do it with a shell script, for example, but it is getting very messy.) `textmerg` is great. Whether it should be used here I'm not sure, but it is a fantastic tool. For example, I'll write or export student feedback to a data file, merge it into a template and then print the resulting file. In that case, I don't want 40 or 60 pdfs. I just need to split them once printed. `textmerg` is perfect for that.

Comment: Thank you very much @cfr It worked like a charm. The only thing that I needed to take care of manually was the "new line"s that people had in their responses to a question. I think there should be a way to do that also automatically, before converting it to CSV. Thanks again.